# Changing colour for alternate rows

Tags: php, html-table

I want to make a table more readable by alternating row colours. I've been through the other answers but can't see how to apply them to my code. I tried various toggle methods in the last bit of the code but just broke everything.

I can't use jquery or CSS because I can only access this part of the code.

I want to toglle to bgcolor="#8BC6FD"

```
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 border="thin">
<col width=150>
<col width=100>

    <tr bgcolor="#D4E9FC" style="outline: thin solid">
    <td class="viewN"><b>TYPE:- </b></td>
    <td class="viewN"><b>PACKING:- </b></td>
    </tr>

    <?php 
    $dbconn = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 XXXX password=YYYY)") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

    $query = "SELECT * FROM stock
        ORDER BY name" ; 

    $result = pg_query($query); 
    if (!$result) { 
        echo "Problem with query " . $query . "<br/>"; 
        echo pg_last_error(); 
        exit(); 
    } 

    while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        printf ("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", htmlspecialchars($myrow['type']),htmlspecialchars($myrow['packing']));
    } 
    ?> 
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't use jquery or CSS because I can only access this part of the code.

It's unclear as to which part of code you're referring. Assuming you can access all the code showed, you can place the `<style>` tag before or after the `<table>`.

It's as simple as defining n-th CSS like

```
<style>
    /* tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #0000cc} */
    tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #D4E9FC}
</style>
```

Comment: You can literally place a <style> tag right before or after the table.

Comment: Oh that is nice, been fluffing around for ages